# Animation on top another resource agent animation 3D

Tags: anylogic

How can I place an agent animation over another resource agent animation in a 2D simulation?

I already moved the order in the Palette but still the seized resource gets on top of the attached agent.
In the image below, the agent is the white triangle and the seize resource is the blue truck, I need to see the triangle on top of the blue truck. The truck doesn’t has a presentation item in the Palette I don’t know why, still it appears in the simulation.

[Palette vs Animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKUPk.png)

In the 3D animation everything looks correct because I have the Z coordinate set correctly, is the 2D animation the one with the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must ensure that your truck agent animation is part of Main as well.

Likely, you will need to have them in a custom agent population and your ResourcePool needs to add new units to it (you can set this up under the "Advanced" properties of the ResourcePool).

Then you can "layer" it below your white triangle using API calls as described in the [help here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/presentation/editing-presentation-shapes.html?resultof=%22%70%72%65%73%65%6E%74%61%74%69%6F%6E%22%20%22%70%72%65%73%65%6E%74%22%20%22%73%68%61%70%65%22%20#changing-stacking-order-position).